# Excel VBA - Giving a variable the date from 8 days ago

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to reference 8 days ago in my code however i'm having trouble. What i have so far is this:

```
LastSundayDate = Format(Now - 8, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
```

But this returns the value 00:00:00

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Comment: What data type is your `LastSundayDate` variable?  Is it `String`, or something else?  (If I run that code, allowing `LastSundayDate` to be a `Variant`, it sets `LastSundayDate` to be a `Variant/String` containing `"02/Nov/2017"`)

Comment: `Public LastSundayDate As Date`

Comment: If defined as a `Date`, the code generates `2/11/2017` for me.  (The `Format` is pointless - you are converting to a string and then implicitly converting back to a date.  You may as well just say `LastSundayDate = Date() - 8`)

Comment: Where are you seeing the `00:00:00`?  In the watch window?  Or are you doing a `Debug.Print LastSundayDate`?  Or are you placing the value of `LastSundayDate` into an Excel cell?  Or what?

Comment: Just when i `Debug.Print LastSundayDate`, i'll give `LastSundayDate = Date() - 8` a go

Comment: If `LastSundayDate` is declared `As Date`, a `Debug.Print LastSundayDate` should display the value in your current date format, so it is **very** strange to display just a time format.

Comment: I see where i'm going wrong. The code with the `LastSundayDate` variable is the initial code that formats the page. The issue occurs when you close the Workbook, reopen it and run a macro that is linked to `LastSundayDate`. Obviously since it's been closed the variable is no longer assigned.

Comment: I was just about to say something like that - the only time you would get `00:00:00` would be if the date was zero.  So was going to ask whether the `Debug.Print` was directly after it was set.  Anyway, it sounds like you now know the cause of the problem.

Comment: How would I go about comparing dates? I've set LastSundayDate as a Public Date (`Public LastSundayDate As Date`). It's now returning the correct number (02/11/17). When i put it in the following IF statement `If Cells(i, 19).Value > LastSundayDate Then`, where values in Cells(i, 19) are of the format DD/MM/YYYY, it doesn't pick up anything

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to give us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to help.  Just giving one line from your program wasn't enough to solve your first issue (because the problem was linked to the fact that you were setting the value in one place, and then using it in a completely different place), and I suspect that this new issue (which should be raised as a new question) could be similarly dependent on more lines of code than just `If Cells(i, 19).Value > LastSundayDate Then`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to use DateAdd to add/subtract from dates

```
lastsundaydate = DateAdd("d", -8, Date)
```

Comment: You can happily subtract numbers from dates.  A date is just a number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
LastSundayDate = Format(Date - 8, "dd/mmm/yyyy")
```